# How to push Data into existing Document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My problem is I want to push data on to a specified position in an array in a MongoDb Document, but when I push the new data it doesn't add it to the right position.

When run this update statement:

```
collection.update({ "schraenke.name": "Schrank1" }, {
                    $push:
                    {
                        "schraenke": [{
                            "masterbricks": {
                                "sensor1": { value: "test" }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });`
```

The result from the above update is the document:

```
{
    "_id": "55599876095c6bac18209dfa",
    "name": "Serverraum1",
    "schraenke": [
      {
        "name": "Schrank1",
        "nummer": "1",
        "reihe": "1",
        "masterbricks": {
          "name": "Mastrebrick2.0",
          "uid": "6dKiRt",
          "he": "1-20",
          "sensor1": {
            "name": "Temperatur",
            "uid": "qvf"
          }
        }
      },
      [
        {
          "masterbricks": {
            "sensor1": {
              "value": "test"
            }
          }
        }
      ],

    ]
  }
```

The value field should be added to `"sensor1"`, but it adds a new array.

My expected result is:

```
{ 
    "_id": "55599876095c6bac18209dfa", 
    "name": "Serverraum1", 
    "schraenke": [ 
        { 
           "name": "Schrank1", 
           "nummer": "1", 
           "reihe": "1", 
           "masterbricks": { 
               "name": "Mastrebrick2.0", 
               "uid": "6dKiRt", 
               "he": "1-20", 
               "sensor1": { 
                   "name": "Temperatur", 
                   "uid": "qvf", 
                   "value" : "test" 
               } 
           } 
       }, 
   ] 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected result? Should your `value` field be an array or just a single value?

Comment: My expecting result is:

{
    "_id": "55599876095c6bac18209dfa",
    "name": "Serverraum1",
    "schraenke": [
      {
        "name": "Schrank1",
        "nummer": "1",
        "reihe": "1",
        "masterbricks": {
          "name": "Mastrebrick2.0",
          "uid": "6dKiRt",
          "he": "1-20",
          "sensor1": {
            "name": "Temperatur",
            "uid": "qvf",
            "value" : "test"
          }
        }
      },
     
    ]
  }

Comment: That the value is add to the sensor1

Comment: @MarcoK **chridam**'s answer will work for you.

Comment: Yes this works fine. But its overwrite the existing. What i try to get is, that the value ist add to sensor1 everything time i execute the query

Comment: so you mean the `sensor` document must have a `value` filed which is an array of measured values?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) you need to apply the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to push the new document into the right position. The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.collection.update({ "schraenke.name": "Schrank1" }, 
    {
        "$set": {
            "schraenke.$.masterbricks.sensor1.value": "test" 
        }
    }
)
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "55599876095c6bac18209dfa",
    "name" : "Serverraum1",
    "schraenke" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Schrank1",
            "nummer" : "1",
            "reihe" : "1",
            "masterbricks" : {
                "name" : "Mastrebrick2.0",
                "uid" : "6dKiRt",
                "he" : "1-20",
                "sensor1" : {
                    "name" : "Temperatur",
                    "uid" : "qvf",
                    "value" : "test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)  adds the array field with the value as its element.

You should use [$Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```
collection.update({ "schraenke.name": "Schrank1" }, {
                    $set:
                    {
                        "schraenke": [{
                            "masterbricks": {
                                "sensor1": { value: "test" }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Your Example overwrite the existing data, dosent add anything to it.

Comment: Check  @chridam's answer. It should be just overwrite "value" field not the sensor1

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$push` then `"value" : ["test"]` array will added into `sensor1` using following update query :

```
db.collectionName.update({"schraenke.name":"Schrank1"},
  {"$push":{"schraenke.$.masterbricks.sensor1.value":"test"}})
```

Instead of `push` use `$set` as mentioned above **chridam** and used `upsert` `true` in set.

Comment: [`Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert)

Comment: Yes a want to add a new value and the value should not be overwritten, it should create a new value array

Comment: My new query is: `collection.update({ "schraenke.name": "Schrank1" }, { $set: { "schraenke.$.masterbricks.sensor1.value": "Test" } }, { upsert: true });`
But its overwriting the existing value